# YouTube API v3 - Quota Increase Request

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there still a way how to request for higher quota limit? In the Google console there is the following link (https://services.google.com/fb/forms/ytapiquotarequest/) where one should be able to send a request for higher limit, but due to unsupported Captcha tool it is not possible to send out the form.

[image]

Can you please help or provide guidance?

This question is raised here as per Google Team's instructions (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support).

Comment: Are you getting any error? if there's any, can you share it here so everyone will have a visibility of what's wrong?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 Image added. As the Captcha cannot be filled in due out-of-order status, the form cannot be sent. Please see this on the first link provided.

Comment: We're still seeing the same issue as of today (2018-10-05), and typing random words in the reCAPTCHA does not work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you, but what I did was I typed in two random words and the captcha worked. You just need to put two words (any words) and the form will submit.

Just a warning, I did this a week ago and haven't heard back from Google. I think they don't read these requests even if we submit them anyway. I also submitted a question similar to yours asking "when will my request be looked at" and no google engineers answered. They seem to not care or bother to look at stackoverflow even though they SAY they do on their support page.

I'm out of options now how to increase my quota limit, so the feature I wanted to add to my app will just have to be put on hiatus since i can't use it if google does not increase my quota.

I honestly don't think google will even look at my request. This has happened before and i haven't heard a response for over a year on another request I sent.