# Youtube liveBroadcast insert limits?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm providing management of live streaming to the International Sporting Competition. At the request of the client we're using YouTube as a delivery platform. I've built an interface so the events and stream keys can be easily managed outside of the Youtube API. Ideally I would like to insert all events, so end users can have a direct link to the YouTube event.

After inserting 30 events (inserting at a rate of 1 per second) I seem to have hit an undocumented limit. I get a 403 error "request not authorised". I can still use the credentials for other actions so I have not crossed the global quota for the user or the account.

Unfortunately the [Youtube API increase form is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281897/youtube-api-v3-quota-increase-request) so I cannot contact Youtube there and request a rate increase.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a limit of 50 liveBroadcast.inserts(). This may be per 24 hour period I will confirm tomorrow. The web gui confirms that it is denying my requests because I have made too many live events and to try again "later".